# How filter decimal input in PHP and sanitize it

Tags: php, input, decimal, user-input

I want filter the user's input of a decimal value and I want allow commas and points.

I'm using the following piece of code to accomplish it:

```
$user_input = round(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'test', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION|FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND),2);
```

With the first filter all works fine if I enter decimal values with points, but if I enter a decimal value with commas the function is deleting the comma and the decimal part too.
Could someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this, like this one:

```
preg_match_all('/^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{1,})?)$/', $input, $output);
```

In the $output variable you'll get the results. If the output it's not correct you'll just get an empty array.

To see how the preg_match_all method works go here:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php

And to know more about regexps go here:
http://php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: Perfect! Thakns you, it works fine; just one tip, into the output variable I'm getting an array with two identicals arrays inside and the first position of each array has the right value, is it normal?

Comment: Sure it is, on that regexp we are capturing a float divided-by commas/points, but we are surrounding the pattern with parenthesis, so we get an array of two positions yet they have the same exact results. If you change the pattern to this: /^\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{1,})?$/' you will get an array of just one position, and the regexp/output will remain the same.

Comment: Okay, perfect! Thanks you for the explanation, I really appreciate it.